# Visual studio 2022 text editor faded out for code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, text-editor, visual-studio-2022

Suddenly, the text in all classes and all projects fadded out. This could be from WINDOWS 10 also, Any registry setting?
My color theme is -> System settings & same issue with light or blue theme.
I have tried

1. Text-Editor settings -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Advanced -> Font formatting
2. Reset all settings under:  Tools -> Import & Export settings wizard

Any option to restore back it normal clear view.

[image: Visual studio screen shot]

Wtih dark theme
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting dark theme and see if it's faded also ?

Comment: With dark theme it looks like fine, its white in font color then.
Added screen shot in original question.

Comment: Do you have an extension installed called 'Codist' ?

Comment: No, there is no such extension installed.

Comment: Hi @Gufran Khan, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find solution, so I repaired it from control panel and it resorted everything to default.
Issue is fixed now.

Comment: Hi @Gufran Khan, could you clarify what exactly have you did to fix the issue? I have the same problem on Windows 10 and VS 2022 17.4.1

Answer (score 2):

I've faced with the same problem after update of Visual Studio to 17.4.1. I use Blue theme.

I've tried to reset settings but this didn't help.

What helped me - I changed text editor font from **Courier New** to **Consolas**. To do this it's needed to go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors:

[image: Fonts and Colors]